# Pass array into laravel bcc mail list

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

Im getting undefined variable errors when trying to insert a bcc list and names.

```
  $query = DB::table('users')->get();
  $bcclist = "";
  $bccnamelist = "";
  foreach ($query as $key=>$user) {
    $bcclist .= $user->email.",";
    $bccnamelist .= $user->username.",";
  }

  $email = '';
  $data = Input::all();
  Mail::send('emails.buildsoftheweek', $data, function($message) use ($email){
    $message->to('admin@buildsanctuary.com', 'All Users')
            ->bcc("$bcclist", "$bccnamelist")
            ->subject(Input::get('emailsubject'));
   });
```

How can I do what I want here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variable scope issue. You have to add `$bcclist` and `$bccnamelist` to `use()`:

```
Mail::send('emails.buildsoftheweek', $data, function($message) use ($email, $bcclist, $bccnamelist){
$message->to('admin@buildsanctuary.com', 'All Users')
        ->bcc("$bcclist", "$bccnamelist")
        ->subject(Input::get('emailsubject'));
});
```

---

Also there's no need to put those variables in a string. This should work as well:

```
->bcc($bcclist, $bccnamelist)
```

Comment: Oh easy enough! Thanks :)

Comment: @user2921557 : If the answer helps you. You shall accept the answer by marking the Ticket Icon to the left side of the answer.